# How to prove this identity using L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: limits

Any idea how to prove the following identity?

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\Gamma(-1-n+\epsilon)}{\Gamma(-1-n)} + \frac{1+\epsilon+n}{1+n}=1 \hspace{1cm} \text{for n } \in \mathbb{Z^+}$$

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\Gamma(-1-n+\epsilon)}{\Gamma(-1-n)} + \frac{1+\epsilon+n}{1+n}=2 \hspace{1cm} \text{arbitrary n }$$

I tried to do it by hand the following way:

$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\Gamma(-1-n+\epsilon)}{\Gamma(-1-n)} + \frac{1+\epsilon+n}{1+n}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\Gamma(-1-n+\epsilon)}{\Gamma(-1-n)} + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1+\epsilon+n}{1+n}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(-1-n)}{\Gamma(-1-n)} + \frac{1+n}{1+n}\\
&= 2\\
\end{align}$$

I believe that the following step is wrong, when $ \text{n } \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

$$\begin{align}
& \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\Gamma(-1-n+\epsilon)}{\Gamma(-1-n)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(-1-n)}{\Gamma(-1-n)}\\
&=1\\
\end{align}$$

But I don't know how. I have verified both identities on Mathematica 12.2.

[image: Mathematica Output]

Comment: Can you please reformat your question to make it clear? Use mathjax to write mathematical expressions, here is a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @5xum Thanks for your comment. I have edited it.

Comment: It would be great if you can include your working for both the limits so that mistakes if any can be fixed. Also this will help you to get more familiar with mathjax for future endeavors on this website.

Comment: THe question doesn't make sense to me. How could the second limit be different, if in the second limit, it **could** be that $n$ is in $\mathbb Z^+$?

Comment: @5xum I also don't understand precisely how the second limit is different. But I have verified on Mathematica 12.2 that the identities are correct!

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks for your comment! I have added it.

Comment: @Epsilon the identities, as written, are contradictory. What happens if $n=2$? According to the first identity, the limit should be 1, but according to the second limit, the limit should be 2.

Comment: @Epsilon In other words, the two identities are like the statements "all cheeses go great with meat" and "all goat cheeses go horrible with meat". The two statements cannot both be true, because for a given goat cheese, the first statement says it *does* go with meat, but the second says it doesn't.

Comment: In the first case, positive-integer $n$ makes $-1-n$ a negative integer, for which $\Gamma$ is undefined, so that's a problem. (As far as the $\varepsilon$-limit is concerned, $n$ is a *constant*. If such a constant already breaks your function, then there's nothing to discuss.) ... On the other hand, for $n$ such that $\Gamma(-1-n)$ *is* defined, the value is finite, and you don't have a L'Hospital's Rule situation; the limit follows from the continuity of $\Gamma$.

Comment: BTW: The presentation is unnecessarily complicated. The limit of the polynomial fraction is obviously $1$, so you can simply remove it (and subtract $1$ on the right). Moreover, $\Gamma(-1-n)$ (when defined) is a constant, so you can factor it out of the limit; you might as well clear the fraction by multiplying on the right. So, (ignoring the problematic first limit) your second limit statement reduces to $$\lim_{e\to0}\Gamma(-1-n+e)=\Gamma(-1-n)$$ for $n$ at which $\Gamma(-1-n)$ is defined. (Ie, the  limit is equivalent to stating that the Gamma function is continuous wherever it's defined.)

Comment: Mathematica's handling of certain "undefined" expressions requires caution. Eg, MMA says `1/0` is `ComplexInfinity`; this is not-unreasonable in certain contexts (or else it wouldn't be allowed to happen), but is clearly problematic in others. MMA likewise evaluates `Gamma[-3]` to `ComplexInfinity`. Correspondingly, in the limiting context, MMA appears to consider `Gamma[-3+e]/Gamma[-3]` a not-infinite value divided by an infinite value (aka, zero); and, in turn, dutifully evaluates the `e->0` limit as zero. ... So, MMA "verifies" your first limit, but not in a universally-acceptable way.